# 2 factor login for gui and ssh imposes verification for sudo use

Tags: debian, security, sudo, login

**tldr: how can I make it so I don't have to use a verification code to `sudo`?**

Hello,
I followed [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/208205/how-to-use-two-factor-authentication-on-your-linux-desktop-with-google-authenticator/) on how to setup 2 factor login for my debian install.
I have it so when you try to login through the gui or the virtual terminals you have to use a verification code.

This has also made it so every time I want to `sudo` for the first time in a while I have to enter a verification code and my password.

I don't mind putting my password in, but also having to put in a verification code is a little much. How can I make it so I don't have to put in a verification code for using `sudo`?

Comment: If you follow the guide, the sudo configuration isn't changed. Which files did you modify?

Comment: I modified `/etc/pam.d/gdm-autologin` and `/etc/pam.d/sshd`

Comment: are you sure you didn't also edit `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` or `/etc/pam.d/sudo`?   check with `grep pam_google_authenticator /etc/pam.d/*`

Comment: oh, it seems it is also in `common-auth`, but no where else besides the other two files previously stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `pam_google_authenticator.so` enabled in `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`.

`common-auth` is included in (almost) every other file in `/etc/pam.d/` - that's its purpose, to provide common authentication rules for programs that use `pam`.

If you don't want every program to use google 2-factor auth, delete it from `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`.

Comment: This solved the problem. Another part was since I am using `gdm` and the tutorial uses `lightdm`, I had put the google auth in the wrong `gdm` file.
The correct file to put it in is `gdm-launch-environment`.